# I'm writing in PHP for a church website, and keep getting a syntax error related to a string without any visible problems

Tags: php, joomla, amazon-s3

The error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home2/svchapel/public_html/mmp_upgrade/administrator/components/com_sermonspeaker/s3/S3.php on line 1802

The line of code referenced is:

```
'code' => (string)$rest->response->body->Error->Code,
```

The line above the code referenced is:

```
$rest->response->error = array(
```

And the line below the code referenced is:

```
'message' => (string)$rest->response->body->Error->Message);
```

I can't find a problem in any of these lines... help?

Answer (score 0):

Might be some odd, but invisible character there which ruins the PHP syntax (e.g., some sort of a fancy hyphen character instead of a regular one). I would try carefully re-typing the whole line manually in the plain text editor; if that doesn't help, I'd try to insert line breaks before each `->` to see where exactly PHP borks up.